# Run while true in systemd script

Tags: bash, shell-script, systemd

I got a bash script essentially runnning this:

```
#!/bin/bash

[...]

 while true; do
         str="broadcast "`randArrayElement "messages[@]"`
         server_send_message $str
         sleep $interval
 done
```

Now I want to run this as a systemd service, my service script looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Announcer
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/somescript &; disown
ExecStop=/usr/bin/kill -9 `cat /tmp/somescript.pid`
Type=forking
PIDFile=/tmp/somescript.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Unfortunately when I run this service via `service somescript start` it is working but because of the while true loop my terminal is stuck in starting the script:

```
● somescript.service - somescript service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/somescript.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Wed 2016-08-17 12:22:34 CEST; 43s ago
  Control: 17395 (somescript)
   CGroup: /system.slice/somescript.service
           ├─17395 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/somescript &; disown
           └─17409 sleep 600
```

How can I run this script as a service without being stuck in "starting" /  the while true loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to let systemd work for you.  Let it handle the forking at the start and the killing of the process.  Eg replace your service part by

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/somescript
PIDFile=/tmp/somescript.pid
```

then you can use `systemctl start`, `status` and `stop`. You must remember that the lines in systemd are *NOT* interpreted by the shell, so for example your `&;` is merely passed as another parameter of 2 characters to your script.

Comment: Okay thanks, I did the changes. Unfortunately the script still hangs when trying to start it as before.

Comment: Did you remember to do `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`?

Comment: You know these moments you think you already did something though you did not? Thanks it works! :)

Comment: in my case i have to add /bin/bash too

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan Make sure you have done `chmod a+rx` on your script file so that it is executable, and that the first line is `#!/bin/bash` if it is a bash script.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements you might consider to replace your loop by a systemd timer configuration. It will not start service twice even if server_send_message takes longer than "OnUnitActiveSec":

somescript.timer

```
[Unit]
Description=Announce every minute

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=1m
AccuracySec=10s
Unit=somescript.service

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

somescript.service Service part:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c 'str="broadcast "`randArrayElement "messages[@]"`; server_send_message $str'
```